# Fetch on Page and component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a component `<Categories/>` on the `main` page. and on the `main` page I'm using `fetch` to dispatch an action.

in my component `<Categories/>`, I use fetch as well which is working just fine.

I have `refresh token` implemented in nuxt so if I went to the `main` page and my token expired the `refresh` URL gets called once. but it doesn't! it gets called twice ... if I only used fetch on `main` page only it works as expected.

```js
  async fetch() {
    await this.$store.dispatch(
      "pub/getalll",
      "/api/u/all?limit=" + this.pageSize + "&page=" + this.currentPage
    );
  },
```

I know I can handle `<Categories/>` on `main` page fetch but i wanted to control the fetch state for the component itself .

On  `<Categories/>` I tried on `mounted` but the URL keeps getting called twice. and also `fetchOnServer: false`

in all other pages where I have `fetch` or `asyncData` the `refresh` URL gets called once only .which is the expected behavior.

I don't understand where the issue is? any idea?

Comment: So, you do have a `fetch` on both page and the component? `refresh` refreshes all the lifecycle hooks.

Comment: @kissu yup I have on both .

Comment: This is the correct behavior so. `refresh` is not the method to go here. You should probably emit an event to call the hook again with some homemade code. If you want the other way around, you can use `$children` and make some condition there. Something like this: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/discussions/9277

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question . if I use fetch in both comp and page the `refresh token` endpoint on `nuxt/auth` module gets called twice on the page

Comment: Hm, you probably need to be double-sure that this is coming from here. Try to `console.log()` there. Then, maybe a debounce may work? The scope will be hard to define tho..

Comment: well, a debounce works just fine !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP solved his issue of the `auth` module being triggered 2 times with a `debounce`!